# Baked texture map shows weird distortions, is it mistake or not?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

[image]

After i baked diffuse map i got these weird distortions, but i don't know if i should worry about them and unwrap mesh differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subdividing your UV map with a *subdivision modifier*.

Go to the subdivision modifier and uncheck **UV Smooth**, if you don't want to subdivide the UV map.

From [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html):

> **UV Smooth**
>   How to handle UVs during subdivision.